# how do callback from internal service with filter?

Tags: feathersjs

a help, while consuming another internal service eg:

```
await Promise.all (messages.map (async message => {
      // Also pass the original `params` to the service call
      // so that it has the same information available (e.g. who is requesting it)
      message.user = await app.service ('users'). get (message.userId, params);

    }));
```

I get all the records,
email, avatar, _id.
How do I get only email back ...?

tks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `$select` in `query`. [feathers select](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/querying.html#select)

Comment: How would you use inside the hook, could you give an example ... tks